# How to install python3.4 in home 'not root'? ensurepip failure

Tags: linux, python-3.x

I do not have root privileges on the Red Hat Linux machine I am installing python3.4 on.

Downloaded Python-3.4.1.tgz

```
tar -xzf Python-3.4.1.tgz
./configure
makealtinstall --with-ensurepip=install prefix=~ exec-prefix=~
```

Python3 does install, but I don't have pip.
I get the following error:

> Ignoring ensurepip failure: pip 1.5.6 requires SSL/TLS

I don't have root access so I cannot install via:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev openssl
```

I do have a working version of openssl.

Does anyone have suggestions I could try?

Comment: If you do not need pip to be installed during installation, and just on the system, you can install it afterwards by downloading [get-pip.py](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py) and running `/path/to/my/python get-pip.py`

Comment: I get another error zlib not available.  I'm thinking I will get these errors on any install version that I try to use on the server without root.

Comment: I did end up using [anaconda installer pm](https://www.continuum.io/downloads).  This ended up being the best solution for me.

Answer (score 5):

Since you are in RedHat, you have to install openssl-devel

> yum install openssl-devel

Or you can install it later with get-pip.py

Comment: The main aspect of the scenario from the question is, that the user does not have root privileges, i.e. he cannot use the `yum install` command. Using `get-pip.py` does not solve the missing openssl problem. Your answer essentially told the user exactly what the user wrote he cannot do.

Answer (score 2):

The complete procedure for installing Python 3.4 with pip3/pip3.4 on RHEL7 is below. For Ubuntu 12.04 LTS replace yum with apt-get, openssl-devel with libssl-dev and you are good to go:

```
sudo yum install -y gcc make openssl-devel openssl
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.4.3/Python-3.4.3.tgz
tar -xf Python-3.4.3.tgz
cd Python-3.4.3/
./configure --with-ensurepip=install
make
make install
```

Alternatively, you can run make altinstall depending on whether you need create python link or not.

Comment: Thanks! I thought that ensurepip would be there by default, but it required the extra parameter `--with-ensurepip=install` like you said.

Comment: The question was about a non-root (means no sudo) solution!